# How to fix akiraz2 Blog URL Rules error in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I installed this blog extension - https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/akiraz2/yii2-blog on my yii2 app. It works perfectly and I can access the blog page on `mysite.com/frontend/web/blog` link. 
I am using Yii Advanced template and in my `frontend/configuration/main.php` I have the some url rules added which works well for static pages but not the blog which results in page not found.

I added the code below to remove `site` from the the static pages:

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            ],
        ],
```

However, this result into `page not found` for the blog pages which I can earlier view with `mysite.com/frontend/web/blog`

I think I need to add a rule that will help me access the blog main page at `mysite.com/blog` and the blog posts at `mysite.com/blog/post-blog-article`

**UPDATE:**

After some troubleshooting, it looks like the blog extensions works without even adding any rules. Same goes for pages created inside controllers apart from SiteController. Once I add the rules above to get rid of the `site` in url of pages created inside `SiteController.php`, everything else stop working while only the SiteController pages work. Any idea of how to either limit the rule to SiteController pages alone or a set of rules that allow all to work together?

Comment: are you saying that before adding the rule you were able to access the blog by the url `mysite.com/frontend/web/blog` and after adding it says `404 not found` ?

Comment: Yes that was what happened. And when I remove the rule, the blog start working again. When I add the rules back, I got 404 again.

Comment: Any suggestion on fixing this? I have not been able to resolved this.

Comment: This rule`'<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',` cause all other controllers that are not SiteController including the blog to result into page not found. Is there a way to limit this rule only to SiteController? I have also tried `<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>` and it only works for SiteController.